# How to access the non-application arguments given to spark submit?

Tags: apache-spark

From [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit) link:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class> \
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key>=<value> \
  ... # other options
  <application-jar> \
  [application-arguments]
```

How can the scala code in `main-class` access the arguments specified BEFORE the `application-jar`?

Comment: do you mean non spark variables?

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible. The closest thing you can do is get the value of the property defined in your spark-submit example from the SparkSession object.

```
spark.conf.get("spark.master") //master
spark.conf.get("spark.submit.deployMode") //deploymode
this.getClass.getClassName // main class :)
```

or else create a wrapper script around spark-submit that relays all the arguments as application argument to the main class.

Comment: we need to access those variables in order to create the SparkSession object :) why? because we want to set the spark.cassandra.output.throughput_mb_per_sec depending on how many executors and cores we are running with